# Avocado indoor tree wilting

Tags: trees, indoors, tree-care, avocado, wilt

I am not sure why this is happening, some information the top 2cm soil is cocounot soil, the soil beneath I believe is just normal indoor plant potting soil.

This is the pot, about 26cm wide and 23cm deep. Leafcutter for scale lol.
[image]

Here you see a whole image of the plant. As you see leafs seems weak, but it's still growing and the stem is getting thicker slowly.
[image]

Here's the newly sprouted leafs, wilting..
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are having root rot.

Root Rot (Phytophthora cinnamomi): This fungal disease is one of the most severe threats to avocado trees. It causes the roots to decay, leading to the yellowing and wilting of leaves and the potential death of the tree. The best defense is prevention through good drainage, careful watering, and resistant rootstocks.

You may find detailed information on Avocado trees, both indoor and outdoor on [Gardenfrontier's web page](https://gardenfrontier.com/growing-avocado-trees-made-easy/).

Answer (score 0):

Needs a prune, an avocado left to grow by itself without pruning or chopping of the uppermost part makes it weak, tall and lanky. Prune and use a high Nitrogen and high potash based fertilizer and if possible give it a wee little bit more sunshine.